# Visual Studio reading old/stale registry

Tags: visual-studio-2012, registry

Visual Studio 2012, VS 2012 Command Prompt, VS 2010 Command Prompt, and a C++ console application compiled in 64-bit with VS 2012 are all reading an out of date instance of various registry keys.  Each application (i.e. VS 2012, the command prompts, and the compiled app) all seem to have their own version of this out of date registry.  Below are the symptoms I'm seeing and my various attempts to fix it.

I've both added new registry entries and updated the data in existing ones and all appear updated in HKLM\Software\ viewing them with RegEdit and using 'reg query ' in a normal console window.

Using the VS Command Prompt I perform the same query and get registry entries prior to my updates.  If I open up a VS 2012 command prompt and perform edits using command line arguments the registry for that VS 2012 command prompt is now different than the registry read by the VS 2010 command prompt.  It is also different from the VS 2012 IDE and the application built from VS 2012.  They seem to have their own instances of whatever version of the registry they are reading from.

Finally, I opened up the Visual Studio 2012 command prompt and typed Regedit.  It opened up RegEdit and it was viewing the old registry!  All of the stale values within HKLM\Software\ were present - a seemingly completely separate version of the registry.  Where is it getting this from?

My environment: Windows 7 Enterprise, VS 2012 Ultimate, console application built in 64-bit.
It should be noted that I have not made any major environment changes that I recollect and this is a new issue on my previously working development system.  My colleagues have the same/similar environment and hardware setups with the same code base and have never encountered or seen this issue.

Things I've tried.

- The almighty reboot
- Uninstalling / Re-installing VS Studio 2012 as well as wiping out my code base, pulling it fresh and rebuilding (brute force I know...).
- Checking the Registry for Wow6432Node keys to see if the reads/writes are getting redirected (I do not have a HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node and no other instances of that key have the old stale data or much else for that matter)
- Searching the entire registry for the stale keys/values/data I'm seeing (not found anywhere)
- Turning off virtualization using 'reg FLAGS  hklm\software\ SET DONT_VIRTUALIZE DONT_SILENT_FAIL RECURSE_FLAG' as well as variations of this with one flag at a time.
- Writing and debugging a unit test to try and determine anything.
- VS 2012 safe mode
- VS 2012 logging to see if the log file could shed any light on the problem.
- Cursing (quietly because I'm at work)
- Bribes (my workstation has yet to respond to these attempts)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm close performing a clean Windows installation on my workstation but would rather save myself the time and trouble of setting everything up again :)

Comment: Please stop destroying your machine, there isn't anything wrong with it.  You'll need to learn the role of the [Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on a 64-bit operating system.  Ask questions about it at superuser.com

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the File System Redirector.  I'm still not completely sure what is happening but after some more tests it appears that a different registry hive is getting loaded for my Visual Studio command prompts (both 32/64-bit), Visual Studio, and the console application in question.  I'm not sure why this new behavior started considering the console application has always been a 64-bit process but at least now I can edit the other registry hive as a workaround until I determine why this is happening.